# IndexOutOfRangeException, but there is no out of range

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to do a little school homework. So for the input, it will be any name like Mike.

But we need to check if the name is actually in English. If it is, then output will be "Hello, NAME"
I did the checking for english letter by checking the ASCII code for each letter and to see if it's actually part of the english alphabet ASCII codes. Also done that using an array of booleans.

My code is as follows :

```
string name = Console.ReadLine();
bool[] isEnglish = new bool[name.Length];
int num = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i<=name.Length;i++)
 {
      for (int ii = 65;ii<=122;ii++)
      {
          if(name[i] == (char)ii)
          {
              isEnglish[i] = true;

              break;
           }
       }
}

for (int iii = 0; iii<=name.Length;iii++)
{
     if (isEnglish[iii] == true)
     {
         num++;
     }        
 }

if(num == name.Length)
Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}!", name);

else
Console.WriteLine("name isn't in English");
```

and I'm getting Error :

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at Solution.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00024] in solution.cs:14 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at Solution.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00024] in solution.cs:14
```

so the error as its line 14? I don't see anything wrong in line 14. I'm stumped

Comment: i actually didn't copy the 'main' function and the usings' so minus that it will be line 8. (14-6)

Comment: You can use one cool feature it is called debug. Also we don't know which is line 14.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Oh, and an array of length five has indices 0,1,2,3,4.

Comment: C# uses the Unicode character set with its UTF-16 encoding. So, you are talking about the [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) letters. Tip: Use 'A' instead of 65 because it's easier to read. (BTW—Not all names are "like Mike." Billy Ray, D'Arcy, Déanne, Mary-Ann,….) All-in-all, be careful not to learn the wrong thing from CS exercises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= name.Length; i++)
//and
for (int ii = 65; ii <= 122; ii++)
//and
for(int iii = 0; iii <= name.Length; iii++)
```

to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
//and
for (int ii = 65; ii < 122; ii++) // but this case may work for you without changes
//and
for(int iii = 0; iii < name.Length; iii++)
```

Indexing starts from `0` to `Length - 1` (always lower than `Length`), but your indexes are from `0` to `Length` (not to `Length - 1`) -  you should change `<=` to `<`

Answer (score 1):

You are going out of bounds because you are looping from 0 to the length of the array. If array has 3 elements its length will be 3 but its indexes will be 0,1,2.
And you are looping from 0 to length so your index goes 0,1,2 **and** 3.
You need to loop from 0 to **length-1** and that should fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

There absolutely is a `IndexOutOfRangeException`, when `i == name.Length`. Mind the zero-based indexing.